# How to get some part of JSON for jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I am using a webapi in jQuery DataTables `aaData` property like this:

```
 "aaData": "http://api.example.com/v1/asdasd/sms/latestoutbox.json?pagesize=1000",
```

this request return one JSON like this:

```
{
"return":
    {"status":200,"message":"Accept"},
"entries":
[
    {"messageid":40859622,"message":"Text1","status":14,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431868680,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40859621,"message":"Text2","status":10,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431868680,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40859589,"message":"Text3","status":14,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431868620,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40858860,"message":"Text4","status":10,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431867960,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40858483,"message":"Text5","status":10,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431867600,"cost":146}
]
}
```

but I just need to "entries"'s  rows to pass it to my `aaData` like this:

```
    {"messageid":40859622,"message":"Text1","status":14,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431868680,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40859621,"message":"Text2","status":10,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431868680,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40859589,"message":"Text3","status":14,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431868620,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40858860,"message":"Text4","status":10,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431867960,"cost":146},
    {"messageid":40858483,"message":"Text5","status":10,"statustext":"Waiting","sender":"300007575","receptor":"0911111111","date":1431867600,"cost":146}
```

How I can work on

```
"aaData": "http://api.example.com/v1/asdasd/sms/latestoutbox.json?pagesize=1000",
```

to get my necessary values?

Comment: assuming you store it in var data = {...}, then data['entries']

Comment: i explain my question, please help how change url to get my neccessary values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [sAjaxDataProp](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sAjaxDataProp) (DataTables 1.9) or [ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) (DataTables 1.10), below is an excerpt from the manual:

> By default DataTables will look for the property 'aaData' when
>   obtaining data from an Ajax source or for server-side processing -
>   this parameter allows that property to be changed. You can use
>   Javascript dotted object notation to get a data source for multiple
>   levels of nesting.

Below is proper initialization code for different DataTables versions.

**DataTables 1.9.x**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "http://api.example.com/v1/asdasd/sms/latestoutbox.json?pagesize=1000",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "entries"
  });
});
```

**DataTables 1.10.x**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "http://api.example.com/v1/asdasd/sms/latestoutbox.json?pagesize=1000",
        "dataSrc": "entries"
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function AssignResult() {

    //Call Web API
    var result = { //Get the Result
        "return":
        { "status": 200, "message": "Accept" },
        "entries":
        [
            { "messageid": 40859622, "message": "Text1", "status": 14, "statustext": "Waiting", "sender": "300007575", "receptor": "0911111111", "date": 1431868680, "cost": 146 },
            { "messageid": 40859621, "message": "Text2", "status": 10, "statustext": "Waiting", "sender": "300007575", "receptor": "0911111111", "date": 1431868680, "cost": 146 },
            { "messageid": 40859589, "message": "Text3", "status": 14, "statustext": "Waiting", "sender": "300007575", "receptor": "0911111111", "date": 1431868620, "cost": 146 },
            { "messageid": 40858860, "message": "Text4", "status": 10, "statustext": "Waiting", "sender": "300007575", "receptor": "0911111111", "date": 1431867960, "cost": 146 },
            { "messageid": 40858483, "message": "Text5", "status": 10, "statustext": "Waiting", "sender": "300007575", "receptor": "0911111111", "date": 1431867600, "cost": 146 }
        ]
    };

    var aaData = result.entries; //aaData will have all the entries.

}
```

Hope this helps.